# Create a Haskell type class that can define a function that counts the occurrences of two values

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am trying to create a type class that defines two functions. One called numMatching. It takes two values and return the count of occurrence the first value in the second value. For example: numMatching 1 1 = 1 since the first value 1 appear once in the second value 1. numMatching 1 0 = 0 since the first value never appear in the second value 0.

For now I have defined the class:

```
class Counter a where
    numMatching :: a -> a -> Int
    numNonMatching :: a -> a -> Int
```

and I am trying to create an instance of this class for Int types but I am really
confused.

```
instance Counter Int where
    numMatching a b =
        if a == b
            then 1
            else 0
```

I tried to run this function in the ghci by input numMatching 1 1. It should return a value of 1 but I got an error says I need a type annotation to specify what a and b is.

Error: [image]

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: This compiles fine for me after I fix the indentation in the numMatching definition. What exactly is the compiler error, and are you sure it's pointing to this code?

Comment: @Erik It has no compiles error but it does not work if I put something like numMatching 1 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" (that is, what did you expect to happen)?

Comment: @Avioddddd If it doesn't have a compiler error, why does your question say it does? Please put a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited my question and put a screenshot on it

Comment: That clarifies things a bit. It would be better, though, if you copied and pasted the error as text, and not as an image (you can copy from the Windows console by selecting with the mouse and then pressing Enter).

Comment: Tangential question: if your class isn't just a type system experiment, do you have any other instances for it in mind?

Comment: @duplode yep. Its for homework tho but I have to create other instance for Char, Lists etc..

Comment: That's fine. I asked that because in the first version of your question you mentioned an example with lists, and that left me wondering. (The obvious type for a `numMatching` for lists would be `Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int`. `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int` might make sense, but then you'd have to decide what should happen with e.g. `numMatching [6,2] [5,1,6,2,4,2,1,6,6,3]`.)

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, the type of `1` is not `Int`, but rather:

```
GHCi> :t 1
1 :: Num p => p
```

That means the `1` literal can stand for a value of any type which is an instance of `Num`, the specific type being determined by how you use it. That is why, for instance, both `1 + 2 :: Integer` and `1 + 2.5 :: Double` work: `1` is an `Integer` in one case and a `Double` in the other one. The type of `(+)` is...

```
GHCi> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

... so if you say the result of `1 + 2` should be an `Integer`, GHC will infer that the types of `1` and `2` there should be `Integer` as well, because the result of `(+)` has the same type of its arguments.

Now, let's have a look at the type of `numMatching`:

```
GHCi> :t numMatching
numMatching :: Counter a => a -> a -> Int
```

We know the result of `numMatching` is an `Int`, but, unlike what happens with `(+)`, that tells us nothing about the type of the arguments. As a consequence, GHC doesn't have enough information to decide which instance of `Num` should be picked as the type of the `1`s in `numMatching 1 1`. That is what "ambiguous type variable [...] prevents the constraint [...] from being solved" means. One of the consequences of this inability to pick a type for `1` is that there is no way to choose an instance of `Counter`, or even decide whether there actually is one (e.g. you have defined one for `Int`, but not for `Double`). That is why you get a separate error mentioning `Counter`.

To avoid this issue while leaving your instances as they are (i.e. keeping your `Int` instance and not having to add any other ones), add an explicit type annotation to either of the `1`s that you pass to `numMatching`:

```
GHCi> numMatching (1 :: Int) 1
1
```

Note that if one of the arguments already has a concrete type, no extra annotations are necessary:

```
GHCi> :{
GHCi| foo :: Int
GHCi| foo = 1
GHCi| :}
GHCi> :t foo
foo :: Int
GHCi> numMatching foo 1
1
```

For the sake of contrast:

```
GHCi> numMatching (1 :: Double) 1

<interactive>:64:1: error:
    * No instance for (Counter Double)
        arising from a use of `numMatching'
    * In the expression: numMatching (1 :: Double) 1
      In an equation for `it': it = numMatching (1 :: Double) 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this awesome explanation :)